# Filtering magento's product attributes with other attributes

Tags: php, magento, advanced-search

I am working on Magento's advanced search.

I search by 4 attributes. Now, when I select one of the attributes, I'd need to reload others to disable ones that won't fit with selected one. It is possible in some easy way?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter this way:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');  
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('orig_price');    

//filter for products whose orig_price is greater than (gt) 100
$collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
    array('attribute'=>'orig_price','gt'=>'100'),
)); 

//AND filter for products whose orig_price is less than (lt) 130
$collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
    array('attribute'=>'orig_price','lt'=>'130'),
));
While this will filter by a name that equals one thing OR another.

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');  
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('orig_price');    

//filter for products who name is equal (eq) to Widget A, or equal (eq) to Widget B
$collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
    array('attribute'=>'name','eq'=>'Widget A'),
    array('attribute'=>'name','eq'=>'Widget B'),        
));
```